# Fastest Way to Calculate Minimum Haversine Distance between Lat Long & an array of Lat longs in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, databricks

**Context**: I am looking for a way to efficiently calculate, in PySpark, the distance between a pair of lat longs and an array of lat longs and then taking a minimum of those distances.

## How this would work:

- Step One: I have a *Spark* Dataframe containing restaurant ids with latitude & longitude as columns

```
# Something like this

>>> restaurants_df
restaurant id | lat   | long 
123           | 32.34 | 54.62
```

- Step Two: I have a *Pandas* data frame consisting of gas stations

```
>>> gas_stations_df
gas_station id | lat   | long 
456            | 76.22 | 64.24
789            | 24.65 | 35.55
```

- Step Three:
  I now want to calculate the haversine distance between each restaurant and ALL the gas station locations and then get the minimum distance! So let's say:

  - Haversine Distance b/w restaurant id **123** and gas station **456** = 5m
  - Haversine Distance b/w restaurant id **123** and gas station **789** = 12m

Then I want to return 5m as the value since its the lowest distance. I would like to do this for ALL restaurant ids. Some sudo code to better understand this issue:

```
# Sudo code to understand desired logic
for each_restaurant in a list of restaurants:
    calculate the distance between the restaurant and ALL the gas stations
    return minimum distance
```

## PROGRESS SO FAR

So far I have employed the use of Vectorized Pandas UDFs and normal UDFs as follows

```
def haversine_distance(lat, long):
    """Get haversine distances from a single (lat, long) pair to an array
    of (lat, long) pairs.
    """
    # Convert the lat long to radians
    lat = lat.apply(lambda x: radians(x))
    long = long.apply(lambda x: radians(x))

    unit = 'm'
    single_loc = pd.DataFrame( [lat,  long] ).T
    single_loc.columns = ['Latitude', 'Longitude']

    other_locs = gas_stations_df[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].values  # this is a pandas dataframe

    dist_l = []
    for index,row in single_loc.iterrows():
        .... do haversine distance calculations
        d = haversine distance


        dist_l.append(np.min(d) )

    return pd.Series(dist_l)
```

Then I apply the Pandas UDF as follows:

```
restaurant_df = restaurant_df.withColumn('distance_to_nearest_gas_station', lit(haversine_distance('latitude', 'longitude')))
```

Although this approach works, it's still rather slow to scale and I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do this?

Thank you very much for reading!

Answer (score 2):

I would ignore the "haversine" requirement for the beginning and filter it down to a few points using a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Nearest_neighbor_search) (in either 2 or 3 dimensions), which should be very fast.  If you want/need the exact distance at that point you can use whatever formula you'd like.